# Exclude a particular Revision from Subversion directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I have multiple revisions in my SVN Repository.

Say 5-10. Now I update the local directory pointing to SVN. So, the directory will be updated to the latest revision. (Here it is 10)

Now, If I want to remove the revision number 7 from my local directory, how should I proceed.

Still I need 5,6,8,9,10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you have local directory updated to 10th version and you want to exclude from local directory files/modifications added in the 7th version ?

Comment: At the top of your local directory, run  'svn merge -r -7'   Note the '-' before the 7.  SVN will tell you something like: --- Reverse-merging r7 into foo.   If you want to get it back, type svn merge -r 7

Comment: As of svn version 1.7, the command is
'svn merge -c -7 .' to omit revision 7 from your working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to revert changes from a specific revision.

The way depends on SVN client. For example, in Tortoise SVN you may open log of a directory, right click on the revision you want to revert and select "Revert changes from this revision".

Take into account that sometimes it may not succeed if there were some changes overlapping with changes being reverted.